# Arrayadapter Android Duplication

Tags: android

I have a problem with an arrayadapter, for a list view. Apparently its correct, but when I modify the first element, it automatically changes the sixth element. If I do so with the second element, the seventh changes....whats the problem?

```
public class Adaptador extends ArrayAdapter{


    public Adaptador(Context context, String[] objects) {
        super(context,0,objects);
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View listItemView=convertView;
        if (null==convertView){

           listItemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutcartel,parent,false);


        }
       ImageView img=(ImageView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.img);

switch (position) {
    case 0:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.uno);
        break;
    case 1:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dos);
        break;
    case 2:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.tres);
        break;
    case 3:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.cuatro);
        break;
    case 4:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.cinco);
        break;
    case 5:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.seis);
        break;
    case 6:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.siete);
        break;
    case 7:
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ocho);
        break;
}
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you are modifying the data..and call array_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(): there...

Comment: im using an edit text in the custom layout. Then, when in the mobile i try to fill the edit text number 1, the number 6 fills too....

Comment: this is how i invoque an fill the adapter:    String []arr={"","","","","","","",""};
        Adaptador adaptador=new Adaptador(this,arr);


        ListView lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);